# Are there any USDC off-ramp providers to convert USDC to Fiat currency for a Custodial Wallet?

Tags: blockchain, wallets, polygon, cryptoeconomics

We have a custodial wallet created for each of the users of our application. They should be able to purchase the NFTs using USDC in the platform. Users should be able to on-ramp and off-ramp USDC from the application itself. I have been looking for providers that does this and was able to get one provider known as [transak](https://transak.com). But they have a daily limit of 5000$ and a monthly limit of only 10000$ for off ramp. This won't work in our case. Are there any other services that has an increased off ramp limit and a nominal processing charge?

P.S: The reason I'm bringing the custodial wallet here is if the user has to sign any message as part of off-ramp then it has to happen on the server side and the provider should allow the same.